# Screen stuck at the Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot, login, 17.10

I've using Ubuntu 17.10 for a few months. It has been working great until today. When I switch on my computer, the usual Ubuntu logo appears and I wait a few minutes but nothing happens. I've waited for half an hour and nothing happened. I restarted several times but the problem persists. I don't know what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Can someone please answer. I really need to get my system working. All my work is saved in there. And it's due tomorrow.

Comment: I don't know. I think it might be a 2gb graphic card.

Comment: I can't. At least not right now. Do you think there might be some other problem?

Comment: I really need to get this working right now

Comment: Could it be anything else other than that? Is there anything I can do right now?

Comment: what was your last action about installing/updating when last success login?

Answer (score 3):

Check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

The `fsck` found and fixed errors on your file system, but the system continues to not boot fully. Other file corruption is possible. Booting to an older kernel works fine.

If you wish to continue to try troubleshooting the non-booting kernel, follow the procedure shown below, otherwise boot to the newest booting kernel, backup your files, and reinstall Ubuntu, then do Software Updates.

- use the first method from my original instructions and boot to the newest kernel (that doesn't fully boot), and get to the `#` prompt.
- type `sudo pico /etc/default/grub` and use the arrows keys to navigate to the line that contains `"quiet splash"` and delete the words `quiet` and `splash` so that you're left with `""`. Remember this line, as you'll need to reinsert those words back later, once the machine boots properly.
- `control-o` # to save the edit
- `control-x` # to exit the editor
- `sudo update-grub` # to update grub
- `reboot` # to reboot the computer

The machine still won't fully boot, but it'll show you on the screen where it's stopping, along with any error messages. Report back. Edit your original question with any important details, and then send me a comment that starts with `@heynnema` to alert me.

Comment: I tried the above procedure.  I went into the recovery mode and did whatever you suggested. It showed some errors and I fixed them. But when I rebooted, the problem is still there. Apart from this, there has been some other development. When I chose "ubuntu, with linux 4.13.0-31-generic" it booted fine and I was able to use my system normally. What does that mean? Is it okay if I keep doing this? If no, then what is the solution?

Comment: @RitchieSudarshan there may be some file corruption that `fsck` won't fix. If booting with "ubuntu, with linux 4.13.0-31-generic" is NOT the most current linux kernel that you have installed, then your last software update may have installed a bad newer kernel that's not booting. You'd have to risk deleting the 3-4 files related to the newer non-booting kernel and try to reapply the software update. If that doesn't work, you may have to backup your important files, wipe the disk, and reinstall Ubuntu. Did you install any dkms drivers on the newest kernel?

Comment: I don't know what dkms drivers are. And "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-31-generic" is not the most recent kernal. But is it okay if I keep using it? If no, then I guess I'll have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @RitchieSudarshan Follow my update in my answer and report back.