# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on old computer, stuck on first startup at logo screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, asus

I have a very old laptop, an [ASUS Eee PC 1005P](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/Eee_PC_1005P_Seashell/specifications/), that I just wiped clean and reinstalled with Ubuntu. I finished the installation from a boot USB drive, but then after that on first startup, it got stuck at the logo screen. The dots would just run, and then my screen would flash black. It's been like so for 15 minutes now.

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020614/screen-stuck-at-the-ubuntu-logo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020614/screen-stuck-at-the-ubuntu-logo) - this helped me

Comment: With just 1Gb of RAM I would install Lubuntu, because Ubuntu with Gnome will be sluggish at best.

Comment: Drive enumeration may change from the original serup when removing the USB-drive.  Does it work if you put the drive back in.

Answer (score 1):

Your Asus eee PC 1005P does not meet the [minimum system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for Ubuntu, as its Atom CPU has a [maximam memory capacity](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42503/intel-atom-processor-n450-512k-cache-1-66-ghz.html) of 2 GB. However, there are [flavours](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) of Ubuntu which are less demanding, yet will run Ubuntu apps, [freely downloadable](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours). In particular, [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) is the least demanding flavour with its [LXQt](https://lxqt.org/) desktop.

I would suggest you make a new LiveUSB installer with Lubuntu, and install Lubuntu on your PC, erasing the old Ubuntu install.