# Boot stuck at Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot

When I reboot the system, bios was updated and after that it stuck on Ubuntu logo. I tried the suggestions here: [Screen stuck at the Ubuntu logo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020614/screen-stuck-at-the-ubuntu-logo) 
but after choosing recovery mode, it is hanging on the message `A start job is running for Create Volatile Files and Directories ( Xmin Ys / no limit)`. Also, after rebooting, `couldn't get slze: 0x8000000000000e` and a bunch of other errors are shown. Then Ubuntu logo comes and stuck in that.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Can you check BIOS was updated correctly, e.g. by booting another OS (even using a USB drive)?

Comment: Yes, I could boot into windows with no issue.

Comment: I found that this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/987488/boot-stuck-at-a-start-job-is-running-for-create-volatile-files-and-directories?newreg=452497d37c8847559548fc7b825a6310 , is similar to my problem and OP wrote he/she solved it after "using my boot flag" in the comments of an answer. What does it mean? It might solve my issue.

Comment: Usually when the BIOS is updated it resets to the factory default values. Is there something different than when you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Please advise which version of Linux was installed (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop,. Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) and the version's release number.

Comment: Okay, so I have left computer overnight in boot screen and the next morning it started successfully. I don't know if the problem occurs again though. I have removed `tmp/`, so I hope it will not repeat.
Thanks everyone.