# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck at boot screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot with Windows 10. It worked fine until yesterday when it just got stuck at that black screen with "Ubuntu" written at the bottom. I tried disabling file check during boot, getting into recovery mode, restarting gdm3 service, changing boot config to `nomodeset`, but nothing seems to work. I also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020614/screen-stuck-at-the-ubuntu-logo) (removing `quiet splash` from GRUB config) and got this output:

[image: boot screen]

There was a lot of stuff passing by, but this is where it got stuck (the only other error I recall having been able to see was that it failed to load the docker service quite a lot of times). Also, the only thing I did that could've caused this is `systemctl mask tmp.mount` (to install tensorflow), and then [probably] forgetting to unmask it, and apparently I can't unmask it from recovery mode. Is there any way to fix this problem?

**EDIT:** As asked in the response, here is what I get from `journalctl --since today` (and it does seem like the trouble comes from the masking that I forgot to remove):

[image: journalctl output]

Everything else in the output seems fine, and I don't see any error at the end of the output as well:

[image: journalctl output 2]

Is it possible to remove this mask in recovery mode? As I mentioned, I have tried `systemctl unmask tmp.mount` but that doesn't work.

Comment: When you write "I have tried systemctl unmask tmp.mount but that doesn't work", what exactly do you mean by that? Is there any error message? Is it still masked after you try to unmask it? I found this helpful as an explanation of what "masking" means: https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-masking-units/

Comment: @Elias it says `Failed to unmask unit: File /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount: Read-only file system` and it stays masked. I checked [this link](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-systemctl-how-to-unmask/) and the file indeed is a symlink to `/dev/null`, but I'm a bit reluctant to just delete this symlink file since I don't know whether systemd would automatically create/access the original location to /tmp

Comment: Side question: I tried to create a copy of this symlink file (for backup) but it gives the same `cannot create regular file...read-only file system` error on even copying into my home directory. Is this related or just an artifact of recovery mode?

Comment: boot al live-linux and make filesystemcheck fo all your linux filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

- Choose recovery mode
- Drop to root shell prompt
- Press Enter
- At the root shell prompt, type `journalctl --since today`
- Look through the resulting journalctl log to find out what was happening just before your system got stuck on the last attempt

Hopefully that can give more info that can be helpful. For example, it if turns out that it gets stuck initializing some particular service/package, you could try disabling or removing that service/package.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of what you said, please see if this can be fixed (and sorry for the late response)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem too, I am not quite sure how it worked but i feel it can work on you too. first i switched to recovery mode. restored all the options in the menu later after pressing ok,I clicked alt-F2 and logged via terminal entered these commands  sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt update waited as usual i had some broken packages repaired them and removed outdated ones but eventually it worked.

**A takeaway i learnt later **
someone suggested to me that in future if i want to switch to newer version of ubuntu it is more efficient to use Cl since it will do magic itself and overwrite the old reinstalling with release requirements. hope this helps.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is "CI" ?